# Look for a particular number and sort it

Tags: awk, grep

Look for a particular word (in this case numericals) in the whole file, sort it and eliminate if it occurs only once.

Input:

```
1. I love my country 1234
2. I love Newyork 5678
3. I love my city 1234
4. I love my pet 1111
5. I love my dog 2222
6. I love my cat 1111
7. I love my cat 5555
```

Output:

```
1. I love my country 1234
2. I love my city 1234
3. I love my pet 1111
4. I love my cat 1111
```

Tried: `sort -u` is not giving the proper results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{c[$NF+0]++; a[NR]=$NF+0; b[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(c[a[i]]>1)print b[i]}' file
```

Using your input file:

```
$ cat file
I love my country 1234
I love Newyork 5678
I love my city 1234
I love my pet 1111
I love my dog 2222
I love my cat 1111
I love my cat 5555
```

The above command produces:

```
$ awk '{c[$NF+0]++; a[NR]=$NF+0; b[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(c[a[i]]>1)print b[i]}' file
I love my country 1234
I love my city 1234
I love my pet 1111
I love my cat 1111
```

#### Multi-line version

For people who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
    {
        c[$NF+0]++
        a[NR]=$NF+0
        b[NR]=$0
    }
    END{
        for(i=1; i<=NR; i++)
            if (c[a[i]]>1)
                print b[i]
    }
    ' file
```

#### Now it works

- `c[$NF+0]++`

  The array `c` keeps track of now many times the number in the last field of each line has appeared in the file.
- `a[NR]=$NF+0`

  Array `a` stores the number in the last field of line under the key of the line number, `NR`.
- `b[NR]=$0`

  For line number `NR`, array `b` stores the line.
- `END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(c[a[i]]>1)print b[i]}`

  After we reach the end of the file, this loops through each line again and prints it if the count in `c` for the number in that line, as given by `a`, is greater than 1.

Comment: Works really good. Thank you!

Comment: is it possible to remove unnecessary messages from the file after awk, i tried few grep -v "XXXX" it is working fine, but sometimes no repetation (one time string) messages will also gets printed. is there any other better way

Comment: @shivashiva What 'unnecessary messages'?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: Output from awk is perfect, there is no doubt about it.
Here is my question on further filter.

Output from awk
1. I love my A and B 5555
2. I love my B1 and C 5555

Final Output needed:
If i want to further filter I used like grep -v "B1"

Then I end up having the below which is obvious.

1. I love my A and B 5555

as now there are not any repetations anymore, is it possible to elimnate this also from the output.

Comment: @shivashiva If I understand correctly, the solution is to filter first and awk second: `grep -v B1 file | awk '{c[$NF+0]++; a[NR]=$NF+0; b[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(c[a[i]]>1)print b[i]}'`.  (If this gives you what you want, I will update with a simplification to this code.)

Comment: yes right, i tried like this but as i mentioned about sometimes i find single string with no reperations and i want to get rid of these too, 
as grep -v takes one part of the message away and other part stays as it is.

Comment: If you get rid of it first (grep _before_ awk) then how are you seeing a string with no repetitions?  In the above, I showed the input being filtered by grep and _the output of grep fed to awk_.  Awk should not print any line unless it has repetitions.

Comment: For the above mentioned ex i tried like this.

grep "5555" filename.log | grep -v "B1"| awk '{c[$NF+0]++; a[NR]=$NF+0; b[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(c[a[i]]>1)print b[i]}' |less

Output: 
I love my A and B 5555

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  Can you [edit] the question and add to the end of the question (don't change what's there in the question now) sample input that produces that output?

Comment: For the original question, your answer is correct, but i wanted to apply more filter to get easier results for my logs. I dont want to edit the original question but i can post a new one with more example along with your results, only if you dont have a problem with it.

Comment: @shivashiva That's fine with me.